# how to generate call graph with PC-Lint?

Tags: call-graph, pc-lint

I'm having trouble figuring out how to generate a call graph with PC-lint.

I have tried adding the -vhm flag to pc lint but nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me how to get PC-Lint to generate the call graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-vh` option is used to display a graph of the "Strong Type Hierarchy" and the `-vm` option just prints the names of source code files as they are processed.  As of the current version of PC-Lint, there is no way to cause it to display a call graph although there are plenty of [other tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph#Software) that can do this.